# facebook/google account for oauth?

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, facebook-oauth

I have a real quick (And probably easy question) with regards to Oauth that; for the life of me, I can't find on google.

My question is: If an organization wishes to use Oauth for users to authenticate, then does the organization need an account with that particular provider (Google, facebook, twitter, etc) to allow the user to use their credentials to log into an external web portal? And if so: What kind of access does the developer need on said account to properly set up the oauth authentication?

Comment: you should read the official developer docs of those platforms and do some testing with apps. after that, everything will be clear, i guess.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the providers do require an account to issue you developer credentials. This allows them to get in touch with you if there are updates related to APIs.
Most of ten these are normal accounts. in Google case a regular gmail account works. You would want to make sure you share the project with others in the company or create a new account rather than use your personal gmail account   https://developers.google.com/console

I recommend the same thing with other providers that you use/create a company specific account and not your personal account so you can transfer the ownership when needed. https://developers.facebook.com/

Comment: Awesome thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for